# Regex: Rename Files

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to rename a bunch of image files.

They are named inconsistently however there is some logic to it

They all start with an `Id number`

After the `Id` there may be some of the following (Items To Be Removed):

- a space
- 2 letters
- a dash `-`

These will appear in various orders and sometimes more than once, for the space or dash.

The filenames may have any of these items but not necessarily all of them.

Some filenames do have all 3 items.

They may have an additional `_` after this

Then they may have a `number` `{Index}`

Finally they end in `.ext` where `ext = jpg|png|gif...`

Here are some example filenames:

- 1227.jpg
- 1227_1.jpg
- 2200 WH-1.jpg
- 2200WH 2.jpg
- 2200 WH2.jpg
- 2201_BK 1.png
- 2203 RD_1.jpg

I am trying to remove/replace the mentioned items so the filenames are as follows:

`ID.ext` or `ID_{index}.ext`

So the above list would turn into:

- 1227.jpg
- 1227_1.jpg
- 2200_1.jpg
- 2200_2.jpg
- 2201_1.png
- 2203_1.jpg

I have tried writing a few `expressions` but am a little stumped on this one.

I am working on a `PHP` project though other languages would be fine for this script.

Comment: Try [`preg_replace('~^(\d+)(?:[ _-]|[A-Za-z]{2})+~', '$1_', $s)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZyEPM8/1).

Comment: Try [`[a-z _-]+(?=[^.\v]*\.)` replace with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/5eQtmW/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern: `/^\d+\K[-a-z_ ]+/i`
Replace: `_`
([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VLwe4C/1))

Basically only match when there are one or more characters between the id and the index.  Simple.

```
/           #pattern delimiter
^           #start of string
\d+         #one or more digits
\K          #restart fullstring match so that the fullstring match is replaced
[-a-z_ ]+   #match one or more hyphens, letters, underscores, or spaces
/           #pattern delimiter
i           #make the pattern case-insensitive
```

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/081f23ae719d4023c46647dce24f161977a9ed91))

```
$images=['1227.jpg','1227_1.jpg','2200 WH-1.jpg','2200WH 2.jpg','2200 WH2.jpg','2201_BK 1.png','2203 RD_1.jpg'];
var_export(preg_replace('/^\d+\K[-a-z_ ]+/i','_',$images));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '1227.jpg',
  1 => '1227_1.jpg',
  2 => '2200_1.jpg',
  3 => '2200_2.jpg',
  4 => '2200_2.jpg',
  5 => '2201_1.png',
  6 => '2203_1.jpg',
)
```

Question extension solution:  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/llmIV)) ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YgBki))

You can do it with two patterns and replacements on a single `preg_replace()` call or you can use `preg_replace()` then `str_replace()`  to mop up the dangling underscores. This will come down to personal coding preference.  (It could also be done with a `preg_replace_callback()` that checks if there is an `index` number in the image name before adding the underscore, but that will make a more convoluted snippet.)

Codes:

```
$images=['1227.jpg','1227_1.jpg','2200 WH-1.jpg','2200WH 2.jpg','2200 WH2.jpg','2201_BK 1.png','2203 RD_1.jpg','2200 WH.jpg','3000_01.jpg'];
foreach($images as $image){
    echo str_replace('_.','.',preg_replace('/^\d+\K[-a-z_ ]+0*/i','_',$image)),"\n";
}
```

Or

```
$images=['1227.jpg','1227_1.jpg','2200 WH-1.jpg','2200WH 2.jpg','2200 WH2.jpg','2201_BK 1.png','2203 RD_1.jpg','2200 WH.jpg','3000_01.jpg'];
foreach($images as $image){
    echo preg_replace(['~^\d+\K[-a-z_ ]+0*~i','~_\.~'],['_','.'],$image),"\n";
}
```

Comment: Using the `i` pattern modifier shortens the pattern -- this is always my preference.  Writing both ranges into the character class will have the same effect.

Comment: Yep, realized that after I asked :)

Comment: It was not a bad question.  Future readers may ask themselves the same thing.

Comment: `var_export` is new to me. The description in the docs states: `It is similar to var_dump() with one exception: the returned representation is valid PHP code.` not sure what that means. how would you use that where you wouldn't be able to with `var_dump`?

Comment: Found one error: `2200 WH.jpg` turns into `2200_.jpg` This does not have an `index` so it should `remove` the `match` rather than `replace`. Thinking that might need to be done with another `preg_replace` statement.

Comment: The only other thing I can see is that sometimes the `index` has a leading `0`. i.e. `3000_01.jpg`, not a biggie though, I could deal with it when parsing the images for importing.

Comment: @ShawnNorthrop: in this case add optional zeros at the end of the pattern: `~^\d++\K[^\d.]+0*~m`

Comment: @Shawn I can't get back to my computer right now.  I updated my answer.  If you have more concerns let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with the following pattern:

```
(\d{4})([^0-9.]*)(\d\.)
```

And with a substitution of `$1_$3`.

Step by step:

- `(\d{4})` - Check for the 1st 4 digits.
- `([^0-9.]*)` - Check for everything that is not a number or a period after the ID.
- `(\d\.)` - Check for ending number and period before extension (This is so we can properly place the underscore)

Adding the substitution means that the 4 digit number will be added to the beginning, all non-number (or period) characters will be removed, and an underscore will be added between the `$1` and whatever is left. If there is nothing after the ID, no underscore will be added, then the period is added inside the substitution as well.

You can view this on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/L7JOou/3) for a very detailed step-by-step of what is going on.

In PHP this would be:

```
preg_replace("/(\d{4})([^0-9.]*)(\d)\./", "$1_", $string);
```

Output:

- 1227.jpg
- 1227_1.jpg
- 2200_1.jpg
- 2200_2.jpg
- 2200_2.jpg
- 2201_1.png
- 2203_1.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Not a PHP person but the regular expression I would use is:

```
/(\d+).*?(\d?)\.(.*)/
```

This will capture the first set of numbers, skip the middle part, capture the number on the end if present, then capture the file extension.

Then in ruby I would do the following:

```
id, index, extension = my_file_name.match(/(\d+).*?(\d?)\.(.*)/)
new_name = id.to_s
new_name += "_#{index}" unless index.empty?
new_name += ".#{extension}"
```